# Combination of ls, xargs and zcat leads to duplicate file name suffixes?

Tags: shell, debian, xargs, cat, gzip

***Disclaimer**: Yes, finding files in a script with `ls` is bad, but `find` can't sort by modification date.*

Using `ls` and `xargs` with `echo` everything is fine:

```
$ ls -t1 ssl-access*.gz | xargs -n 1 echo
ssl-access.log.2.gz
ssl-access.log.3.gz
ssl-access.log.4.gz
[...]
```

Changing `echo` to `zcat`:

```
$ ls -t1 ssl-access*.gz | xargs -n 1 zcat
gzip: ssl-access.log.2.gz.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: ssl-access.log.3.gz.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: ssl-access.log.4.gz.gz: No such file or directory
[...]
```

Duplicate file suffixes?! What is going on here?

---

**UPDATE:**

OS is Debian 5.

`zcat` is a shell script at `/bin/zcat`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
PATH=${GZIP_BINDIR-'/bin'}:$PATH
exec gzip -cd "$@"
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Perhaps try taking a look at your `zcat` executable (probably a shell script) and see if it is auto-appending a `.gz` extension.

Comment: You actually can sort by modified time if you use `-printf %t` (gnu-only) or `-exec stat -c '%X' {}\;` then pipe it to `sort`.

Comment: What happens on your system when you `zcat` a file that is not compressed?

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff: I get the error message `gzip: test.txt: not in gzip format` with return code 1.

Comment: See [Shell script for moving oldest files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22674) for better ways to sort files by date. The only advantage of `xargs` is running the command for a batch of files at once, and you're not using this capability, so don't even consider using it. About the strange behavior you observe: what does `type zcat` show? What is the ***full*** output from `ls -t1 ssl-access*.gz`?

Comment: the zcat that is part of the gzip package is a binary file, not a shell script.  the binary zcat is functionally identical to `gunzip -c`.  On systems that have a compress package installed, in there is already a zcat program that reads `.Z` files, so the gzip edition of `zcat` is installed as `gzcat` (which you noted below you don't have.  can you modify your script to use `ls -t1 ssl-access*.gz | xargs -n 1 gunzip -c` ?

Comment: Ugh, iPhone keyboard and I cannot click on edit. Could you post the output of `ls -alF ssl-access*.gz`? Maybe they are symlinks pointing to missing files.

Comment: Try adding `--verbose` to the `xargs` and `zcat` invocations. It should at least tell you which program is adding the extra `.gz`.

Comment: I was just about to post the output to all the commands you requested when it hit me. In my shell configuration I'm aliasing the `ls` command with `ls -C --color=always --indicator-style=slash --group-directories-first`. The `--color=always` seems to screw everything up when the output of `ls` is reused. I use this option to view colored output even when piping into `less` (got it from [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/scrolling-through-ls-output-without-a-mouse/7178#7178)) What is the correct way of handling this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this problem on my system caused by color ls. In my .bash_profile, I had this:

```
alias ls="ls --color"
```

I found the result by sending it to stat, which printed something handy:

```
$ ls local4.notice-201207* | xargs -n1 -P4 -I{} stat {}
stat: cannot stat `\033[0mlocal4.notice-20120711.gz\033[0m': No such file or directory
```

Look at those null color codes! It was confusing zcat, which attempted to add a .gz suffix to find a file. The problem was easily solved by changing the ls to color=auto, which disables color output when STDOUT is glued to another process instead of a terminal

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, after such a time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an OS where zcat is for compressed files while gzcat is for gzipped ones. In such case, this should work:

```
   ls -t ssl-access*.gz | xargs -n 1 gzcat
```

Edit:

I reproduced a similar but not identical behavior on Solaris:

```
$ ls -t1 *.gz | xargs -n 1 zcat          
c.gz.Z: No such file or directory
b.gz.Z: No such file or directory
a.gz.Z: No such file or directory
```

On a Debian based distribution (Ubuntu), I do not reproduce your problem.

This might work anyway:

```
cat $(ls -t ssl-access*.gz) | zcat
```

or the equivalent:

```
zcat <(cat $(ls -t ssl-access*.gz))
```

or this simpler one that avoids an unnecessary cat

```
zcat $(ls -t ssl-access*.gz)
```

None of these will handle odd filenames like the ones with embedded spaces.

Comment: No `gzcat` on my system.